# How do I replace this XML value in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, replacement

I need a bit of help replacing text in Notepad++

What I want to replace is:

```
<releasedate>19910101T000000</releasedate>
```

With:

```
<releasedate>1991</releasedate>
```

How can I replace all these lines in a file?
Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What about `<releasedate>20201120T123456</releasedate>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

- Go to Search->Replace...
- Tick "Regular Expression"
- Under "Find what" enter `^<releasedate>(....).*</releasedate>$`
- Under "Replace with" enter `<releasedate>\1</releasedate>`

And go! Either Replace All oder step by step

Comment: It works!!! Just a note: as the whole document is tabbed I had to remove the "^" at the beggining of the find what input. So it was: find→<releasedate>(....).*</releasedate>$ But it worked at the end, thank you!!!